# Android studio can't run application

Tags: android, androidx

When i upgraded my Android studio I have problems with running my application. I get the error below as illustrated in my image. What is wrong? I have tried to exclude many files but every time there is a new file that is duplicated.

What to do?

My build.gradle file:

```
 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-ui.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.slidingpanelayout_slidingpanelayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.print_print.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.documentfile_documentfile.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.versionedparcelable_versionedparcelable.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.asynclayoutinflater_asynclayoutinflater.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.drawerlayout_drawerlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.interpolator_interpolator.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.swiperefreshlayout_swiperefreshlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.loader_loader.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.viewpager_viewpager.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.fragment_fragment.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/main.kotlin_module'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.core_core.version'
    }
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache and restart?

Comment: Yes but still the same problem :(

Comment: Have you tried adding `META-INF/android.vectordrawable-animated.version` on your `packagingOptions`?

Comment: @mrjasmin Did you solved this problem?